# Eclipse CDT eclox reference autocompletion

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, reference, doxygen

I just started working with doxygen and eclox (eclipse CDT, C++) and love the whole package. There's only one thing I'm really missing: whenever I try to add a \ref to a function, class or variable, I have to manually remember the (fully namespace qualified) name of what I want to refer to.

It would be AWESOME if it was possible to use the (already existing) code completion feature from eclipse to suggest the right function, class, etc.

Like so:

`/**
text yadayada bla \ref std::str<ctrl + space here> -> complete to std::string so that doxygen understands the link
*/`

Is that possible? I'm actually surprised that I couldn't find anything about this elsewhere. Is everybody really inserting all references manually all the time?
It becomes quite cumbersome when referring to e.g. `imed::helmbus::io::subclasses::CAN_Reader`

Adding a reference to this should work the same way as when I'm actually coding:

`/**
\ref ime<ctrl+space> -> show list of namespaces beginning with 'ime' -> complete to 'imed::'<ctrl+space> -> show list of subnamespaces -> ... -> imed::helmbus::io::subclasses::CAN_<ctrl+space> -> complete to CAN_Reader
*/`

Or is there maybe a place somehwere where I can find out how to do this? Or why it's impossible?

Thanks!